# How to emit event in angular only for particular element?

Tags: jquery, angular, eventemitter, bootstrap-popover

I am creating a directive in angular to make the confirmation popover using the bootstrap popover, though I am mixing jQuery to achieve it. In directive file code is like:

```
@Output() confirmed = new EventEmitter();

constructor(
    private _ElementRef: ElementRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    $(this._ElementRef.nativeElement).popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: `
        <div class="text-center">
            <span class="d-block">Are you sure?</span>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm mt-1">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger py-0" id="btn-confirm">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary py-0">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>`,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'focus',
        boundary: 'window'
    });


    $('body').on('click', '#btn-confirm', () => {
        this.confirmed.emit();
    });
```

And in the component's template file:

```
<input appConfirmation (confirmed)="confirmed()" type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
<input appConfirmation (confirmed)="confirmed()" type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
<input appConfirmation (confirmed)="confirmed()" type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
```

Whenever I click the `#btn-confirm` the `confirmed()` method is executed three times in the component. How can I emit the event for a particular button for a single time?

Comment: it is because all directives will have same button id as `btn-confirm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope your variables correctly, put your hooks on the right functions, follow the HTML rules (IDs are unique), use the framework to its full potential, and I would suggest stop using JQuery, but since you use it, let's roll with it.

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
click(event) {

  const ID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);

  $(this._ElementRef.nativeElement).popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: `
    <div class="text-center">
        <span class="d-block">Are you sure?</span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm mt-1">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger py-0" id="${ID}">Yes</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary py-0">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'focus',
    boundary: 'window'
  });


  $('body').on('click', `#${ID}`, () => {
    this.confirmed.emit();
  });
}
```

This bins the click event to the function, meaning you only create a popover on click and it gets destroyed when you confirm. Your IDs become unique, creating no more conflicts. To ensure that, they're created dynamically.

Comment: (In case it was not clear, you should not have any `ngOnInit` function)

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem but as you suggested to stop using jQuery then how I would be able to initiate popover (whenever the bootstrap is already using the jQuery).

Comment: I don't know what a popover is exactly, but JQuery does nothing more than abstracting complex JS code. If you want some overlay to confirm a user action, [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) provides a dialog, which is way more suited than JQuery. Also, you can simply create your own components and use the Angular's `Renderer` to handle them. That's a good training and teaches you a lot of things about Angular !